# Is it possible to return the values of reference columns to multiple columns in r

Tags: r, reference

I am organizing a large dataset adapted to my research. Suppose that I have 9 observations (records) and 4 columns as follows:

```
z <- data.frame("fa" = c(1, NA, NA, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1), 
                "fb" = c(2, 2, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, 2),
                "initial_1" = c("A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "C", "D", "B", "A"),
                "initial_2" = c("D", "C", "C", "A", "B", "A", "A", "D", "D"))
```

I want to create two new columns, **fa_new** and **fb_new** according to the values of the first two columns, **fa** and **fb**, which are linked to the reference columns, **initial_1** and **initial_2**, such that **fa** == `#` is matching to **intial_**`#`.

For example, as can be seen above, the first record of the column **fa** is `1` which is linked to "A" of **intial_`1`**. Thus, the first record of the new column **fa_new** will be "A". Likewise, the first record of **fb** is `2` which is linked to "D" of **intial_`2`**; thus, the first record of **fb_new** will be "D".

Accordingly, my expectation is:

```
  fa_new fb_new
1 A      D     
2 NA     C     
3 NA     NA    
4 A      B     
5 A      NA    
6 C      NA    
7 A      NA    
8 B      B     
9 A      D
```

Is this possible using r?

Comment: Thanks for updating the data with `dput` which makes lot of things clear. You have labelled data. Also notice that you have value as -3 which gives you that error because there is no -3 column. What do you want to have as value for such negative numbers?

Comment: The negatives will be NAs.

Comment: Check updated answer if it helps.

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you so much and I really appreciate your perfect help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lapply` to do this for multiple columns :

```
cols <- 1:2
init_cols <- paste0('initial_', cols)
new_cols <- paste0(names(z)[cols], '_new')
inds <- 1:nrow(z)
z[new_cols] <- lapply(z[cols], function(x) z[init_cols][cbind(inds, x)])
z
#  fa fb initial_1 initial_2 fa_new fb_new
#1  1  2         A         D      A      D
#2 NA  2         B         C   <NA>      C
#3 NA NA         B         C   <NA>   <NA>
#4  2  1         B         A      A      B
#5  1 NA         A         B      A   <NA>
#6  1 NA         C         A      C   <NA>
#7  2 NA         D         A      A   <NA>
#8  1  1         B         D      B      B
#9  1  2         A         D      A      D
```

The logic here is we create a matrix with `cbind` which has row/column number. The row number is `inds` (`1:nrow(z)`) whereas column number comes from `fa`/`fb` columns which is used to subset `z` dataframe.

---

The actual dataframe is labelled dataset, the following answer should work on the real data.

```
cols <- 1:2
init_cols <- paste0('fuinitials_', 1:94)
new_cols <- paste0(names(z)[cols], '_new')
inds <- 1:nrow(z)

z1 <- data.frame(z)
z1[cols][z1[cols] < 1] <- NA
z1[new_cols] <- lapply(z1[cols], function(x) z1[init_cols][cbind(inds, x)])
```

Comment: It works for this example, I appreciate it! But it does not work for the actual data, showing an error sign " Error: Subscript cbind(inds, x) is a matrix, it must be of type logical." The actual dataset has more than 40 reference columns. I am wondering if I could find a solution.

Comment: As shown in the example this should work for any number of columns. I think you need to adjust the constants as per your dataframe. Few things that you need to check are 1. do `cols` have all the column numbers that you want to create new columns for? In your example we need to create new columns for `fa` and `fb` which are column number 1 and 2. hence, `cols <- 1:2`, you need to change it based on your data. 2. Are you initial columns named in the same way. In your example it is named as `initial_1` and `initial_2` I generate them using `init_cols <- paste0('initial_', cols)`. Can you check?

Comment: If you have trouble adjusting the answer based on your data. You can update your post with `dput(df[1:6, 1:6])` so that we have same data as yours along with column names and can adjust the answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I tested it following the modification the 1 and 2 that you suggested, but still it does not work showing an error " Error in as.matrix(x)[i] : subscript out of bounds". I have a question. Can I separate the fa/fb and the reference columns with the two dataframes? Such as I create a data "y" for fa and fb column and "z" for reference columns for creating the new columns.

Comment: Please update your post with the data using `dput` of your actual data because what you have shown is not what you actually have. So any suggestions in the answer will not work for your data. If you are getting an error using the above code, we need to be able to reproduce that to fix it. Since the answer works for sample data and not for your original data you need to update the example which is similar to your original data.